# urls validation in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

*I have list of urls for particular services .
want to validate all my urls running or not based on response and print the status of particular service is not running. main problem is how to display particular service is not running .*

```
while read url; do
  curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$url"
 # echo " $LINE"
  done < softwareurls.txt
  status="$(curl -Is $url | head -1)"
  validate=( $stats )
  if [ ${validate[-2]} == "200" ]; then
      echo OK
  else
      echo NOT RESPONDING
  fi
```

softwareurls.txt :example

```
service1=http://192.168.70.10:8080/
service2=http://192.168.80.170:9000/shell
service3=http://192.168.10.10:8085/
........
servicen=http://www.sample.com/
```

Comment: You are closing your while to quickly.  Right now, you run curl on every URL, then check the status.  You should move your done statement to the end of the script.  This way it will run curl on every url, check it's status, say if it is good or not, THEN move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

while read service
do
    url=$(echo $service | cut -d'=' -f2)

    status=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$url")
    if [ $status == '200' -o $status == '301' -o $status = '302' ]
    then
        echo "$url: OK"
    else
        echo "$url: NOT RESPONDING"
    fi
done < softwareurls.txt
```

Notes:

- when you extract your line from softwareurls.txt, you have to extract the url from the line.  That is the `url=$()` line.
- curl, with the options you use, will output the http status response from the url.  So just store that value and test on it.  That is the line `$status=$()`.
- Many HTTP responses might be valid.  I assume 200, 301 and 302 are ok.  Since your urls seem to be internal to your setup, you can modify the code according to your need.
- FYI: In your code, you set $status, but in the next line you use $stats.  And $stats was not set.

I hope this helps, Nic.

Comment: `url=${service#*=}`; or better yet read with `IFS='='`; or better yet use a whitespace-separated input format instead. Also the complex `if` could be really elegantly replaced with a `case` statement. `case $status in 200 | 301 | 302) echo "$url: OK";; *) echo "$url: NOT RESPONDING";; esac`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,

```
#!/bin/bash
function validate_url(){
url=http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.16.1.tar.gz
  if [[ `wget -S --spider $url  2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'` ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
if validate_url $endpoint; then
    echo "NGINX-1.16 is a valid URL"
  else
    echo "NGINX-1.16 is invalid URL"
fi
```

https://github.com/laksgreen/URL-validator/blob/master/url_scripts.sh